# Custom QLineEdit, focusProxy and QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: qt5

This problem is driving me nuts so I would appreciate some assistance. Obviously done the usual googling and checking qt docs but have not found any solution.

We need to customize a standard `QLineEdit`. Here is a prototype:

```cpp
class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyLineEdit(QWidget* a_parent)
  {   
    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
    textEdit->setMinimumWidth(width() / 2);
    textEdit->setMaximumWidth(width() / 2);
    textEdit->setMinimumHeight(30);
    textEdit->setTabChangesFocus(true);

    // background color red
    QPalette p = textEdit->palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor(244,20,20));
    textEdit->setPalette(p);        

    textEdit->setVisible(true);

    setFocusProxy(textEdit);
  }
};
```

This shows a `QLineEdit` with a `QTextEdit` on-top of it.

Using the keyboard to change focus works as expected (the `TextEdit` gets the focus and not the `LineEdit`).

Using the mouse to change focus works as expected (selecting the `LineEdit` forwards the focus to the `TextEdit`).

The `MyLineEdit` and regular `QLineEdit` instances are added to a `QDataWidgetMapper`. We obviously use `setModel` method call on the `QDataWidgetMapper` instance.

In the `QDialog`, changing focus from a `QLineEdit` using keyboard or mouse triggers an invocation of our implementation of `QAbstractItemModel::setData`.

In the same `QDialog`, changing focus from a `MyLineEdit` using keyboard or mouse does **NOT** trigger an invocation of our implementation of `QAbstractItemModel::setData`.

This problem seems to be related to the `setFocusProxy` API. When removing `setFocusProxy` line;

- changing focus from a `MyLineEdit` (specifically the `QLineEdit`) using keyboard or mouse does trigger an invocation of our implementation of `QAbstractItemModel::setData`.
- changing focus from a `MyLineEdit` (specifically the `QTextEdit`) does **NOT** trigger an invocation of our implementation of `QAbstractItemModel::setData`.

How can I use `setFocusProxy` and get invocation of `QAbstractItemModel::setData`?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you call `QDataWidgetMapper::addMapping(yourLineEdit, ...);`, an event filter is installed on the `MyLineEdit`/`QLineEdit`.  I'm guessing you need to somehow forward events from the member `QTextEdit` to the `MyLineEdit`.  I am not aware of the ins and outs of `QWidget::setFocusProxy` or why it is not forwarding those events.